# application version when deploy to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elb

After the first *manual* deployment, I am not able to deploy anymore. **I always get errors about the wrong version**.

The version label should be different every time I run the command, right?

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name  myApp --version-label  ver02 --source-bundle S3Bucket="github",S3Key="develop/deploy.zip"

aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name myApp --environment-name dev-test --version-label ver02
```

adding a different version label I got this error:

**An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the UpdateEnvironment operation: No Application Version named 'ver02' found.**

But if I add an existing application version I got this error:

**An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateApplicationVersion operation: Application Version ver01 already exists.**

This is totally crazy :)
Any clue?

Thanks